# model.fit_generator: Error when checking target: expected lambda_2 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (200, 1)

Tags: keras

I implemented a generator to feed the training process, but `fit_generator` throws this error:

> Error when checking target: expected lambda_2 to have 4 dimensions,
>   but got array with shape (200, 1)

It seems that the function is switching X and y at some point, because (200,1) is "y" shape, not "X" shape.

If I test the generator with the code below it works fine:

```
for i in range(32):    
    train = next(train_generator)
    print(train[0].shape)
```

But with the `fit_generator` an error is thrown.

This is my code:

```
import os
import csv

samples = []
with open('data/driving_log.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for line in reader:
        samples.append(line)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_samples, validation_samples = train_test_split(samples, test_size=0.2)

import cv2
import numpy as np
import sklearn

def generator(samples, batch_size=32):
    num_samples = len(samples)
    while 1: # Loop forever so the generator never terminates
        sklearn.utils.shuffle(samples)
        for offset in range(0, num_samples, batch_size):
            batch_samples = samples[offset:offset+batch_size]

            images = []
            angles = []
            for batch_sample in batch_samples:
                name = 'data\\'+batch_sample[0].split('\\')[-1]
                center_image = cv2.imread(name)
                center_angle = float(batch_sample[3])

                if not center_image is None:
                    images.append(center_image)
                    angles.append(center_angle)



            # trim image to only see section with road
            X_train = np.array(images)
            y_train = np.array(angles)

            yield sklearn.utils.shuffle(X_train, y_train)

# compile and train the model using the generator function
train_generator = generator(train_samples, batch_size=int(len(train_samples)/32))
validation_generator = generator(validation_samples, batch_size=int(len(validation_samples)/32))

ch, row, col = 3, 160, 320  # Trimmed image format

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Lambda


model = Sequential()
# Preprocess incoming data, centered around zero with small standard deviation 
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x/127.5 - 1.,
        input_shape=(row, col, ch),
        output_shape=(row, col, ch)))
#model.add(... finish defining the rest of your model architecture here ...)

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch=len(train_samples) / 32, validation_data=validation_generator,
                    validation_steps=len(validation_samples)/32, epochs=3)
```

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: Your last layer must output the same shape as Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a error on load images, the name was not correctly defined. As the `cv2.imread(name)` don't raises a error wen it don't find the image, just returning a None object, the method was returning a empty variable, that causes the error on the network.